# Exrin Isolates and MasterDetailContainer

Tags: exrin

When working with the Exrin Isolates approach you define the stacks in each Isolater. How do you combine it to work with a MasterDetailContainer? 
For example if I want a menu in the old approach I would create a ViewContainer and pass it a stack for the menu and another one for the pages, but with Isolates I'll have a lot of stacks. how should I build the ViewContainer or maybe should I still have only one main stack and use the Isolates only to isolate views and viewmodels?

```
public class MainViewContainer : Exrin.Framework.ViewContainer, IMasterDetailContainer
    {
        private readonly MasterDetailPage r_MasterPage;

        public MainViewContainer(MenuStack i_MenuStack, MainStack i_MainStack)
            : base(eContainer.Main.ToString())
        {
            r_MasterPage = new MasterDetailPage();
            MasterDetailProxy masterProxy = new MasterDetailProxy(r_MasterPage);
            NativeView = masterProxy.View;
            Proxy = masterProxy;
            DetailStack = i_MainStack;
            MasterStack = i_MenuStack;
            RegionMapping.Add(eRegions.Menu, ContainerType.Master);
            RegionMapping.Add(eRegions.Main, ContainerType.Detail);
        }

        public IHolder MasterStack { get; set; }

        public IHolder DetailStack { get; set; }

        public IMasterDetailProxy Proxy { get; set; }

        public bool IsPresented
        {
            get
            {
                return r_MasterPage.IsPresented;
            }

            set
            {
                r_MasterPage.IsPresented = value;
            }
        }

        public void SetStack(ContainerType i_ContainerType, object i_Page)
        {
            switch (i_ContainerType)
            {
                case ContainerType.Detail:
                    r_MasterPage.Detail = i_Page as Page;
                    break;
                case ContainerType.Master:
                    r_MasterPage.Master = i_Page as Page;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to blend the stacks, that you will place in isolates, then it would be a good idea to define all your stacks and keys in a single location.

However, remember that isolates are designed for splitting up large chunks of code into separate modules. I would only recommend a max of 3 isolates for any given project. Using [Feature Grouping](https://xamarinhelp.com/feature-grouping-code/), is a good way to structure you Views/ViewModels in your project, if you have a large project but not quite big enough for isolates.